# Why cant I see my photo in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie to Rails here.
Code where I call my image:

```
 <div class="center-row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-one text-center">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <img src="assets/images/budah.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-two text-center">
    <h2>World</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is on my main view and the systems does not display any indication that the image path is broken.

Here is the CSS code for the div class:

```
.bg-one { background: #efefef; }
```

I know that the image is in the folder. Is there something missing in my CSS statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using rails asset pipeline you do not need to specify the folder. It discards all of the folders and just runs the files from the assets directory.

Try `<img src="assets/budah.jpg" />` instead